# how do i print 6 values per line using the while loop statement in python

Tags: python, printing

here's my code. 
i need some help in figuring out the print function.

```
x=0

while x < 999:
    if x%40 ==0:
        print(format(x,'7d'),end='')
    x = x + 1
```

the print function i tried using is not working for me.
my code won't print out the values how i would like it too. i want it to print out 6 values per line.

i want it to print like this.

```
40 80 120 160 200 240

280 320 360 400 440 480
```

but instead it prints on one straight like please help.

Comment: note, `0` value is also pass the condition `x%40 ==0`, and should be outputted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, there is always a short way to do something :

```
arr = [format(x, '7d') for x in range(40, 999, 40)]
print('\n'.join(''.join(arr[i:i+6]) for i in range(0, len(arr), 6)))
```

Which outputs :

```
 40     80    120    160    200    240
280    320    360    400    440    480
520    560    600    640    680    720
760    800    840    880    920    960
```

Answer (score 0):

On every **6th** time that you print the number, use `print()` as follow:

```
 x = 1
 counter = 0 while x < 999:
    if x % 40 == 0:
        counter += 1
        print(format(x,'7d'),end='')
    if counter == 6:
        print()
        counter = 0
    x = x + 1
```

Output is similar as follow:

```
 40     80    120    160    200    240
280    320    360    400    440    480
520    560    600    640    680    720
760    800    840    880    920    960
```

Comment: how do i leave the 0 out of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use additional variables-counters:

```
x = c = 0
l = ''   # resulting line
while x < 999:
    if x % 40 == 0:
        l += format(x,'7d')
        c += 1
        if c % 6 == 0:
            l += '\n'
    x += 1

print(l)
```

The output:

```
      0     40     80    120    160    200
    240    280    320    360    400    440
    480    520    560    600    640    680
    720    760    800    840    880    920
    960
```